# xls2csv not converting a single worksheet to csv

Tags: csv, converters

I am trying to convert an xls to csv file. In my workbook I have a sheet named `networktab` I need just one sheet out of the entire workbook to be dumped into csv. So I used the following command.

`xls2csv -b networktab london02.xls > london02.csv`

But this still dumps all the work sheets into csv. I am not sure what is missing here. I have used `https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-xls-file-to-csv-in-command-line/` utility.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you're **passing is wrong option** to the command

```
xls2csv -n networktab london02.xls > london02.csv
```

Options available for xls2csv are:

> -b     : the character set the source spreadsheet is in (before)
>
> -n     : **specify the worksheet number/name** to convert (you cannot use this option with -w)

For more info: [Check here](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/KEN/xls2csv-1.07/script/xls2csv)